# Laravel 5.8. How to trim http during validation and check for uniqueness in the table?

Tags: laravel, validation

1. there is a table of shops, in it, we store URLs with HTTP and https already cut off. example: rozetka.ua, comfy.ua
2. from the front to the request for validation, the URL that has not yet been processed arrives, with HTTP or https. For example http://rozetka.ua
3. How to check the site for uniqueness? validation have a check for URL, the option with preliminary HTTP is not suitable.
4. Since the site has already been configured to work with errors and interception of front-line and back-validation, it is necessary to achieve the condition that when validating the request it is an error as if unique. That is the status 422 and the corresponding error object.

So far I have stayed on this option:

```
return [
    'url' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'url',
        'max:255',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
           $url = parse_url($value, PHP_URL_HOST);
           if (Store::where('url', $url)->count() > 0) {
              $fail('The ' . $attribute . ' has already been taken.');
           }
        },
    ],
]
```

Comment: Your code should already work, doesn't it? I cannot quite understand what is your question here? You can make the field in the database unique if that's what's missing..

Comment: so for example user will enter ```https://example.com``` or  ```http://example.com```  and you need to remove http or https and check for the uniquenes in the table in which you are storing without the https or http am i clear

Comment: yes, and if not unique - return error unique with status 422 and same object error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
return [
    'url' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'url',
        'max:255',
        'unique:NAME_OF_THE_TABLE,NAME_OF_THE_COLUMN',
    ],
]
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique)

Or you can create a custom Rule:

```
php artisan make:rule UniqueUrl
```

```php
//UniqueUrl class

public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $url = str_replace(parse_url($value, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . '://', '', $value);
    return Store::where('url', $url)->count === 0; //true if there is no such url, false if there is at least one
}
```

and use it:

```php
return [
    'url' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'url',
        'max:255',
        new UniqueUrl,
    ],
]
```

Comment: does not work.
from the front comes HTTP. in the table links without HTTP.

Comment: *"from the front comes HTTP"* - only http or https too?

Comment: from the front to the request for validation, the URL that has not yet been processed arrives, with HTTP or https.

Comment: This is a good alternative, thanks, but an identical unique error object must be returned, since there is a library that substitutes the corresponding translations in different languages for different types of errors.
therefore, I need it to check for unique, otherwise, my $fail ('The'. $attribute. 'has already been taken.') is enough;

Comment: *"but an identical unique error object must be returned"* - you can define it in the `message()` method inside the Rule class.